# Endpoints Proto Datastore - Inequality filter on query_method

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

When using the endpoints-proto-datastore query_method on an EndpointsModel, is it possible to have an inequality filter passed as a query field?

For instance, say I have a model with a `lastmodified` field, and I want to query for all the records that have a `lastmodified > date`, where date is a value passed to the API by the client.

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  attr1 = ndb.StringProperty()
  lastmodified = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

From the documentation I have seen, it seems like the query_fields is strictly an equality filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to use an `EndpointsAliasProperty` with a name different than the `lastmodified` field. For example, you could do something like was done in the [Picturesque app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-picturesque-python/blob/98dde3b93e88ecd593e8051758f9391b8fd5a6a2/models.py#L358) used as a sample at Google I/O 2013.

First, define your model

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class MyModel(EndpointsModel):

  attr1 = ndb.StringProperty()
  lastmodified = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

then create an alias property which will be used to update the query

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints

from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsAliasProperty

  ...

  @EndpointsAliasProperty(name='modifiedSince', setter=ModifiedSinceSet)
  def ModifiedSince(self):
    raise endpoints.BadRequestException(
        'modifiedSince value should never be accessed.')
```

This property won't ever be accessed, but its setter is relevant to make the query sort on what we want, so we need to define `ModifiedSinceSet` (it needs to come before the variable is reference, as in [the sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-picturesque-python/blob/98dde3b93e88ecd593e8051758f9391b8fd5a6a2/models.py#L358)):

```
import datetime

from endpoints_proto_datastore import utils

  ...

  def ModifiedSinceSet(self, value):
    try:
      modified_since = utils.DatetimeValueFromString(value)
      if not isinstance(modified_since, datetime.datetime):
        raise TypeError('Not a datetime stamp.')
    except TypeError:
      raise endpoints.BadRequestException('Invalid timestamp for modifiedSince.')

    self._endpoints_query_info._filters.add(
        MyModel.lastmodified >= modified_since)
```

Here we convert the passed in value (from the request) to a `datetime.datetime` object and then use it to add a filter to `self._endpoints_query_info._filters` on the current `EndpointsModel` object.

This `_endpoints_query_info` is of course used [in `query_method`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L1485) to create the query that gets passed to your method.

## Another alternative:

You could just parse the value and use introduce your own syntax. For example, accept strings like `lastmodified>=TIMESTAMP` and then parse the timestamp from the statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and for directing to a good example.