# How to filter on ComputedProperty in query_method?

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

How does one query for computed properties?

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  attr1 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

  @EndpointsComputedProperty(property_type=messages.BooleanField)
  def attr2(self):
    return self.attr1 % 2 == 1


@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1', description='My Little API')
class MyApi(remote.Service):

  @MyModel.query_method(query_fields=('attr2'),
                        path='mymodels', name='mymodel.list')
  def MyModelList(self, query):
    return query
```

In this case `query` will always have a filter that will test for `attr2 == False`.

The cause seems to be that the filters are created from an entity created with `FromMessage`.  As `attr2` is a computed property, it cannot be set.  As `attr1` defaults to 0, `attr2` is always False regardless of what is passed in.

Comment: If you want to query on it, it shouldn't be a computed property. The only way to "do this" is to retrieve every entity and then check the computed property. You should read some of the stuff Khan Academy has written about getting expensive stuff out of the way at write time rather than read time.

Comment: @bossylobster Actually, if you want to query on it, it should be a ComputedProperty.  The whole point of `ComputedProperty` is that it stores the computed value in the datastore at write time.  The scenario you describe would be the case with a regular `@property`.  Note that MyModel.query(MyModel.attr2 == True) happily works as expected.  MyModel.query_method shows unexpected behaviour as it cannot set readonly attributes (like ComputedProperty), but it will happily use them in filters.

Comment: My apologies, I was thinking of alias properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for computed properties by setting up a placeholder alias property similar to how inequality queries can be achieved, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17288934/4139124

More specifically, we set up an alias property with a different name from our existing attr1 and attr2 fields.  We also define a setter that gets called whenever the alias property is assigned to, and use this setter to modify the query.  Note that the setter must appear above the alias property:

```
import logging
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb.properties import EndpointsAliasProperty
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb.properties import EndpointsComputedProperty
from protorpc import messages

class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
    attr1 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

    @EndpointsComputedProperty(property_type=messages.BooleanField)
    def attr2(self):
        return self.attr1 % 2 == 1

    def Attr2AliasSetter(self, value):
        self._endpoints_query_info._filters.add(MyModel.attr2 == value)

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(name='attr2_alias',
                            property_type=messages.BooleanField,
                            setter=Attr2AliasSetter)
    def Attr2Alias(self):
        logging.error('attr2_alias should never be accessed')
```

We then update the query_method to accept the attr2_alias field rather than attr2:

```
@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1', description='My Little API')
class MyApi(remote.Service):

    @MyModel.query_method(query_fields=('attr2_alias'),
                          path='mymodels', name='mymodel.list')
    def MyModelList(self, query):
        return query
```

Then, for example, querying for `myapi/mymodels?attr2_alias=true` will return all MyModel entities with attr2 set to true.